# SQL: insert to unique column with shift

Tags: sql

I need to store data with varchar name and Integer intValue. All integer values are unique and I need to keep up that contract

I need to write query to add the element using the following rule: if after insertion there is an intValue duplication - we need to increase intValue of existed element to resolve conflict. Repeat that operation until no conflict left.

Example:

```
B | 2  |                      | B | 2  |
C | 3  |                      | E | 3  |
D | 4  | => insert (E 3) =>   | C | 4  | 
A | 1  |                      | D | 5  |
Z | 7  |                      | A | 1  |
                              | Z | 7  |
```

The only idea is to run update query in a loop but that looks too unefficient.

I need to write this query in Spring JPA, so the only requirement that the query should not be database specific

#### Business case:

Let's say there is a people in the queue. And intValue is position in the queue. So, "Add" means that some person come, pay money and say: I dont wanna be the last in the queue. I want to be, for example, the 3rd. So you take the money and put that person in a queue so other people after him - increments their position.

The only difference from the queue - that in my case there are gaps allowed

Comment: Seems like a very odd requirement. The general rule is to not touch existing data.

Comment: No loop at all,  just Update existing intValue to Max(intValue) + 1 .  Do not worry about filling gaps below max.

Comment: @donPablo is my understanding corrent that in that in your solution you want to move single conflicting element to the end? If yes, you can not do it, you need to shift all elements with intValue >= new element

Comment: @jarlh please look at update. I've added business case for that requirement

Comment: Do you simply want `update t set c2 = c2+1 where c2 >= 3`, `insert into t values (E,3)`?

Comment: @jarlh not really, because there can be a gaps after 3. So you dont need an update value after the "gap". Please look at the example. Your query will update position of Z to 8, while it should remain 7

Comment: But does the gaps matter?

Comment: lets say gaps means there is no person in a queue with this position. So when you insert a person, you need to shift as less people as possible. So you can't update people after the gap

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aha, we might say that the gaps are occasioned by people leaving the queue.

Lets try this.  Loops are inevitable--either server does them, or we can do as SQL.

```
-- prepare test data
declare @PeopleQueue table (pqname varchar(100), intValue  int);

insert into @PeopleQueue

        SELECT 'B' AS pqname, 2 as intValue  UNION ALL
        SELECT 'C' AS pqname, 3 as intValue  UNION ALL
        SELECT 'D' AS pqname, 4 as intValue  UNION ALL
        SELECT 'A' AS pqname, 1 as intValue  UNION ALL
        SELECT 'Z' AS pqname, 7 as intValue  
;
        --SELECT '' AS pqname, 0 as intValue  UNION ALL

Select * from @PeopleQueue;  - verify good test data

-- Solve the problem
Declare @pqnameNEW varchar(100) = 'E';
Declare @intNEW  int = 3;   -- 3 for conflict,  or for no conflict, use 13
Declare @intHIGH int;

IF  EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM @PeopleQueue WHERE intValue = @intNEW )
BEGIN
        -- find the end of the sequence, before the gap
        SET @intHIGH = (
        SELECT  TOP 1
                intValue   
        FROM    @PeopleQueue pq
        WHERE   NOT EXISTS
                (
                SELECT  NULL
                FROM    @PeopleQueue pn 
                WHERE   pn.intValue = pq.intValue + 1
                )
        AND     pq.intValue >= @intNEW
        )
        ;
        -- now Update all from intNEW thru intHIGH
        UPDATE @PeopleQueue
          SET intValue = intValue + 1
          WHERE intValue >= @intNEW
          AND   intValue <= @intHIGH

End;

-- finally insert the new item
INSERT into @PeopleQueue Values (@pqnameNEW, @intNEW);


Select * from @PeopleQueue;  -- verify correct solution
```

Edited--11/28 17:00
Or, estimate the number of Bump-the-Line-Inserts (vs append to the end inserts), and design the intValues to be originally in multiples of ten (10) so that long sequences of updates are minimized.

Comment: Great solution! Based on it, I've created my own version with nested function. Please see my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
update queue 
SET intValue = intValue + 1
WHERE intValue >= 3 
AND intValue <= (
    SELECT q1.intValue 
    FROM queue as q1 LEFT JOIN queue AS q2 ON q1.intValue + 1 = q2.intValue 
    WHERE q2.name is NULL AND q1.intValue > 3
    ORDER BY q1.intValue 
    LIMIT 1
)
```